# Marketing Cloud SQL LinkName starts with instead of contains

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I'm trying to use a query to identify LinkNames that start with a specific name, (Example_), but as a failsafe I don't want them included if the Example_ falls anywhere in the string other than the beginning of the LinkName, because we also have an _ at the end to identify another variable. Is there any way to specify the text has to be *at the beginning* and not use LIKE or CHARINDEX, which include all parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```sql
select
c.jobid
, c.subscriberid
, c.linkName
from _Click c
where c.linkname is not null
and substring(c.linkName,1,8) = 'Example_'
```

Comment: Can this be used if the number of characters will vary between LinkNames? Example_ may be Ex_ or Exam_. Edited to add - I think I answered my own question. I would need substrings for each potential LinkName I want to identify.

Comment: Sure -- just add additional OR conditions for the other patterns.  Keep in mind that an underscore is a [wildcard character](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals) in any LIKE condition.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this should do it for us.